# php global variables not following nested function calls

Tags: php, global-variables, global

I have come across a weird situation.  I am working with a framework that uses a class being declared as a global (yes, I know, please no flame wars about globals, singletons, 'Dependancy Injection' and the like.  I can't rewrite an existing entire framework) to pass the framework settings to functions. The content of the functions themselves are 'include' segments of code.  Who knows what they were thinking...

Anyway, the problem is this: the `global` is being modified in function level1, which makes the changes properly and when the call to level1 is over, the `global` reflects the changes.  if function level2 is called directly, again, the `global` works fine.  But if function level2 is called FROM WITHIN level1, any changes made to the `global` from within level1 up to the point of calling level2 are NOT propagated to function level2.  It acts like maybe the level1 changes are NOT propagated to the `global` until the level1 function exits??

```
global $config;
$config->set('my_var','some_dummy_value');    // set some variable

function level2(anotherparam) { include 'somecode.php'; };
// while the somecode.php include file contains code something like:
global $config;
echo $config->get('my_var');               // <- problem spot
$config->set('my_var','some_other_data');
echo $config->get('my_var');               // <- works as expected


function level1($someparam) {
    global $config;
    echo $config->get('my_var');             // <- works fine.
    $config->set('my_var','new_data_2');     // <- works fine.
    echo $config->get('my_var');             // <- works fine, has new value
    if ($someparam == 'oops') { level2('blah2'); };  // <- calls level2 but level2's global doesn't contain 'new_data_2', but rather 'some_dummy_value' (original value before level1 was called)
};

echo $config->get('my_var');
level1('blah');
level2('blah');
$config->set('my_var','some_dummy_value');
level1('oops');
echo $config->get('my_var');
```

When run, you get:

```
some_dummy_value  // <- original value
some_dummy_value  // <- from func level1 before change
new_data_2        // <- from func level1 after change
new_data_2        // <- from func level2 before change
some_other_data   // <- from func level2 after change
some_dummy_value  // <- reset back to original value
some_dummy_value  // <- from func level1 again before change
new_data_2        // <- from func level1 again after change
//PROBLEM.  You would think the next value would be 'new_data_2', not the previous value of the global
some_dummy_value  // <- from nested call to func level2 before change !!
some_other_data   // <- from the level2 func after change
some_other_data   // <- back in the main program global has func2 value
```

calling function level1 directly work fine.  The `global` is set to "new_data_2", and as long as the input `$someparam` does not trigger call to level2, things work great.  If you call level2 directly the results work as expected, the global gets set, etc.  But if you were to call level1 with `$someparam = 'oops'` and trigger the call to level2 from within level1, the `global` variable in level2 will contain the values of 'my_var' that existed PRIOR to the call to level1.  In other words, changes made to the `global` in level1 prior to calling level2 do not seem to be propagated back into the 'global scope', if you will, until AFTER level1 function exits.  Either that, or it might have something to do with when the code for level2 was included??  I am not sure.  Anybody seen anything like this before?  Have been googling and can't find this unique problem anywhere mentioned.

using php 5.5.12 on a LAMP box (fedora).  Not having the option to rewrite the framework, anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: Generally, walls of text like this don't get decent answers. Break your text up into paragraphs so the question is more legible.

Comment: `level2()` only contains the `include`.

Comment: AbraCadaver - True.  Most functions in this framework consist of included body code.  The code listed in the example above below the "level2" function was meant to be an example of the included code.